# I'm using a audio in my web page i need to play it first time but not on page refresh in php

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using  a audio in my web page i need to play it first time but not on page refresh  in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['audioplayed'])){
 // add code to play audio
 $_SESSION['audioplayed'] = true;
 }

?>
```

you just need to store a boolean in SESSION.

Answer (score 2):

HOW do you play audio?

Apart from that: use a session to save that the page has been loaded and don't play audio on the second load.

Comment: like this 
echo "<embed src='templates/".$this->template ."/images/meccaAdhan.mp3' name='guitar' id='BGS_ID'  autostart='true' loop='false' width='2' height='0'></embed>";